# C++ (Error Message)

Tags: c++

Gday guys and gals. I am an absolute newbie for C++, and not overly computer literate, ok not at all!! (My last computer code attempt was as a kid in 1991, with a 386 DOS machine, so 25 years have not been kind). Anyway to the point. I have just donwloaded a C++ compiler and when on the dos prompt using bcc32c it  finds the program, but brings and error message. (Error: no input files). How do i fix this? please, if this is an easy question, or has been asked 1000 times before, please just humour me, or point me in the right direction. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: you need to have your code files in the current working directory, may be this can help. however it provides example of gcc http://askubuntu.com/questions/125927/compiling-c-code-raising-no-input-files-fatal-error

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be confused as to what the compiler does. The compiler, in this case bcc32c, compiles your source code files into an executable, you need to write your source code in a text editor or an IDE first.

The error message is indicating that you need to specifythe path to the source files that you want to compile, for example, if we assume your code is stored at "c:\mycode\main.cpp" your command would be "bcc32c c:\mycode\main.cpp"

You may have an easier time working with an IDE like Visual Studio or Code::Blocks, command line compiling is not very user friendly, especially for people who are new to coding.

Unless you are dead set on learning C++, I would suggest learning a simpler language like Python first, C++ has a very steep learning curve! Python has a simpler syntax than C++ and is an interpreted language so you won't need to compile anything.